# Migrate from ajax jquery to angularjs $http

Tags: angularjs, ajax, rest, spring-boot

I'm migrating my project from ajax jquery to angularjs. In which the goal of my code is to display the json object to the html table.

I already tried some sample codes in displaying json data/object using angularjs but it still doesn't work.

here is my code in ajax jquery:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        datatype:"json",
        url:"http://localhost:7878/server/getrecords",
        success: function(){
            //alert("Successful!");
        }
    }).then(function(json){
        var user = json;
        console.log(user);
        $.each(json, function(key, value){
            var strappend = '<tr><td>' + value.billingCycle + '</td>'
            + '<td>' + value.startDate + '</td>' 
            + '<td>' + value.endDate + '</td>'
            + '<td>' + value.customerFirstName + '</td>'
            + '<td>' + value.customerLastName + '</td>' 
            + '<td>' + value.amount + '</td></tr>';
            $("table tbody").append(strappend);
            console.log(key);

        });
    });
});
```

I want the expected output to be display all the reports in an html table. I hope you could help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you do it in controller:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:7878/server/getrecords'
}).then(function(response) {
  try {
    $scope.users = JSON.parse(response.data);
  } catch (e) {}
});
```

and in a template:

```html
...
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
  <td>{{user.billingCycle}}</td>
  <td>{{user.startDate}}</td> 
  <td>{{user.endDate}}</td>
  <td>{{user.customerFirstName}}</td>
  <td>{{user.customerLastName}}</td> 
  <td>{{user.amount}}</td>
</tr>
...
```

Better way it's create a service with method `getrecords` and in controller just call this method from service

Comment: i'm having an error in my console saying: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)"

Comment: can you do `console.log(data);` and write what it return

Comment: i already resolve it by chaging the parameter from data to response then assigning it to the scope.users = response.data

Comment: There is no need to `JSON.parse` data as the $http service does it automatically.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what your "user" object looks like, but assuming it contains an array,ng-repeat is a directive that fits the array.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in user">
        <td>{{item.startDate}}</td>
        <td>{{item.endDate}}</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```